# Cipher Output and Input Streams

Tags: android, io, inputstream, outputstream, encryption

I'm attempting to store some encrypted data in the Android filesystem. I'm getting errors I don't understand and empty files. Please help.

Code:

```
private Cipher cipher;
private ArrayList<ConnectionProfile> connectionProfiles;

public void createCipher() throws Exception{
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
}

public void saveProfiles() {
    try {
        if (cipher == null) {createCipher();}
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("connProfiles.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        oos.writeObject(connectionProfiles);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readProfiles() {
    try {
        if (cipher == null) {createCipher();}
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("connProfiles.bin");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);
        connectionProfiles = (ArrayList<ConnectionProfile>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ;
    }
}
```

Traceback:

```
05-09 23:24:39.628: W/System.err(837): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-09 23:24:39.639: W/System.err(837):  at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:884)
05-09 23:24:39.639: W/System.err(837):  at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:95)
05-09 23:24:39.639: W/System.err(837):  at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeShort(DataOutputStream.java:192)
05-09 23:24:39.648: W/System.err(837):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeStreamHeader(ObjectOutputStream.java:1815)
05-09 23:24:39.648: W/System.err(837):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:279)
05-09 23:24:39.648: W/System.err(837):  at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity.saveProfiles(MainActivity.java:39)
05-09 23:24:39.648: W/System.err(837):  at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
05-09 23:24:39.658: W/System.err(837):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-09 23:24:39.658: W/System.err(837):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-09 23:24:39.658: W/System.err(837):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-09 23:24:39.658: W/System.err(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 23:24:39.658: W/System.err(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 23:24:39.668: W/System.err(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-09 23:24:39.668: W/System.err(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 23:24:39.668: W/System.err(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 23:24:39.678: W/System.err(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-09 23:24:39.678: W/System.err(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-09 23:24:39.678: W/System.err(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 23:26:33.878: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(837): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Update:

So now I have

```
private Spinner spinner;
private SpinAdapter adapter;
private Cipher cipher;
private ArrayList<ConnectionProfile> connectionProfiles;
private KeyGenerator keygen;
private SecretKey key;

public void createCipher() throws Exception{
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    key = keygen.generateKey();
}

public void saveProfiles() {
    try {
        if (cipher == null) {createCipher();}
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("connProfiles.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        oos.writeObject(connectionProfiles);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readProfiles() {
    try {
        if (cipher == null) {createCipher();}
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("connProfiles.bin");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);
        connectionProfiles = (ArrayList<ConnectionProfile>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ;
    }
}
```

and:

```
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2109)
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity.readProfiles(MainActivity.java:59)
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-11 22:20:40.658: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 22:20:40.668: W/System.err(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-11 22:20:40.678: W/System.err(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 22:20:40.678: W/System.err(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 22:20:40.678: W/System.err(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-11 22:20:40.678: W/System.err(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-11 22:20:40.678: W/System.err(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Alright so now I'm initializing the cipher and salt in the onCreate, and my methods have gotten significantly more complicated as follows. The end result is a corrupted stream when attempting to read.

```
private Spinner spinner;
private SpinAdapter adapter;
private Cipher cipher;
private ArrayList<ConnectionProfile> connectionProfiles;
private KeyGenerator keygen;
private SecretKey key;
private String salt;
private SecretKey saltedKey;
private static final String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;

public void createKey() throws Exception {
    keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    key = keygen.generateKey();
    byte[] saltedKeyBytes = new byte[key.getEncoded().length+salt.getBytes().length];
    System.arraycopy(key.getEncoded(), 0, saltedKeyBytes, 0, key.getEncoded().length);
    System.arraycopy(salt.getBytes(), 0, saltedKeyBytes, key.getEncoded().length, salt.getBytes().length);
    saltedKey = new SecretKeySpec(saltedKeyBytes, 0, saltedKeyBytes.length, "AES");
}

 private byte[] generateIv() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
      byte[] iv = new byte[16];
      random.nextBytes(iv);
      return iv;
}

public void saveProfiles() {
    try {
        if (key == null) {createKey();}
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, saltedKey, ivSpec);
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("connProfiles.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        oos.writeObject(connectionProfiles);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        FileOutputStream keyOutputStream = openFileOutput("key.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        keyOutputStream.write(key.getEncoded());
        keyOutputStream.flush();
        keyOutputStream.close();
        byte[] iv = generateIv();
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        FileOutputStream ivOutputStream = openFileOutput("iv.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ivOutputStream.write(iv);
        ivOutputStream.flush();
        ivOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readProfiles() {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "key.bin");
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream keyInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        keyInputStream.read(keyBytes);
        keyInputStream.close();
        File file2 = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "iv.bin");
        byte[] iv = new byte[(int) file2.length()];
        FileInputStream ivInputStream = new FileInputStream(file2);
        ivInputStream.read(iv);
        ivInputStream.close();
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        byte[] saltedKeyBytes = new byte[keyBytes.length+salt.getBytes().length];
        System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, saltedKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(salt.getBytes(), 0, saltedKeyBytes, keyBytes.length, salt.getBytes().length);
        saltedKey = new SecretKeySpec(saltedKeyBytes, 0, saltedKeyBytes.length, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, saltedKey, ivSpec);
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("connProfiles.bin");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);
        connectionProfiles = (ArrayList<ConnectionProfile>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ;
    }
}
```

Traceback:

```
05-19 01:08:17.325: W/System.err(843): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
05-19 01:08:17.325: W/System.err(843):  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2109)
05-19 01:08:17.325: W/System.err(843):  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity.readProfiles(MainActivity.java:102)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at com.sajnasoft.down2home.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:132)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-19 01:08:17.335: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-19 01:08:17.345: W/System.err(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-19 01:08:17.355: W/System.err(843):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, i got it working. You are not using the right ivSpec for Cipher initialization. Try this (iv is now a field):

```
public void saveProfiles() {
    try {
        if (key == null) {
            createKey();
            iv = generateIv();
            ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        }
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, saltedKey, ivSpec);
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("connProfiles.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        oos.writeObject(connectionProfiles);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        FileOutputStream keyOutputStream = openFileOutput("key.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        keyOutputStream.write(key.getEncoded());
        keyOutputStream.flush();
        keyOutputStream.close();
        FileOutputStream ivOutputStream = openFileOutput("iv.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ivOutputStream.write(iv);
        ivOutputStream.flush();
        ivOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my test, i didn't use a salt. This could cause problems if the key gets too long, too.

Comment: No, I made sure the key+salt is 256 bits

Comment: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be 16 bytes long. Wait actually that's probably my fault.

Comment: I threw `byte[] iv = null` at the top of your function when I probably should've put `byte[] iv = new byte[16];`

Comment: You should declare it as a field, as you save the key in a field. If the key is not null you wouldn't generate an iv otherwise.

Comment: Having a strange issue now. connectionProfiles is an array that displays in a spinner. The spinner isn't updating when I save. There is no traceback involved. Also not getting saved results shown in spinner when opening after saving. Had this issue in the emulator and not on my device. On my device I am seeing the spinner update, but not recall saved values.

Comment: I am now having the problem on my device also. It seems to have something to do with the files existing.

Comment: Sounds like a different problem. Does the decrypted object equal the encrypted one? If yes, then I would recommend to create a new question.

Comment: I think it might be because generateKey() refers to iv with it's full name (including object type) and it was causing an exception in saveProfiles().

Comment: I wrote a quick test function and the decrypted object does not equal the encrypted one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30793/discussion-between-torben-kohlmeier-and-sajattack)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you forgot to init cipher:
You must tell to cipher that is encrypt or decrypt : 
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);

I think AES need a key to encrypt and decrypt.

Hope this link can help :

http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleCrypt.html

Comment: So now I have it saving but having difficulty reading. Possibly it is creating a different key/cipher when I go to read. I'll update my OP.

Comment: Would it compromise my security if I saved the key to a file in the same place as the encrypted file?

Comment: First. As I know, you must use the same key to encrypt and decrypt.
To write your key on a file I think it's ok. But I think you should add some character after you read from the file. Example your key is : "ThisIsKey_:D". You can save the key value is : "ThisIsKey" and after you read it from file you can append "_:D" to make your key. Hope it help

Comment: I haven't had time to try your solution yet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be pretty simple to decompile the application and retrieve the salt?

Comment: So it's saying I need an iv. Guess I need to save that to a file too?

Comment: 1. To avoid decompile you can use : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html
Or you can encrypt your key with other algorithm before you save the key to file.
2. Sorry, I don't understand about "iv" ???

Comment: yes, you definitely need the iv. whenever you decrypt using AES, you have to use the same iv and key as used for encryption.

Comment: I am using the iv in the latest code I have posted up there. Still not working.

Comment: Where is the salt coming from? Is it hardcoded or generated? You concatenate the generated key with the salt, are you aware of the maximum key length for AES? How long is your saltedKey?

Comment: Are you initializing ivSpec for this line in saveProfiles? `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, saltedKey, ivSpec);` Lower in the same method you create another ivSpec that you don't use: `IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);` What is this for?